# adding tooltip on image control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am adding tooltip text on images of a list  control.

```
<Image Name="testimage1" Visibility="Visible" Height="30" Width="30" Source="/Assets/icons/files.png" Margin="0,0,10,0">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Content="test content"></ToolTip>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

But tooltip is not getting displayed. Please anyone can help here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comment, there are no tooltips on Windows Phone. What would you expect to happen to display a tooltip when there isn't really a hover?

You could try the approach mentioned [here](http://igrali.com/2012/01/07/show-a-tooltip-for-tapped-pushpin-on-windows-phone/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set ToolTip property in C# like this.

```
ToolTip="Test Content"

<Image Name="testimage1" Visibility="Visible" Height="30" Width="30" Source="/Assets/icons/files.png" Margin="0,0,10,0" ToolTip="Test Content">
```

Comment: ToolTip attribute is not available in windows phone toolkit. I also tried by using ToolTipService.ToolTip as <Image Name="testimage1" Visibility="Visible" Height="30" Width="30" Source="/Assets/icons/files.png"  ToolTipService.ToolTip="test content" />